# Sum values and dynamically add to two columns to make values roughly equal

Tags: excel

Sorry for the lengthy title. I'm trying to load balance sites to Domain Group A and Group B based on site visits/traffic. I've captured total visits for each domain, now I'd like to quickly and dynamically place total domains with their respective visits in either group A or group B such that total visits is as close to equal as possible.

For example, here Domain Group B only has 1 site because that site's visits is greater than all other domain visits combined. The rest of the domains were placed into Domain Group A, as their totals were 174,931.

[image]

Is there a way in Excel to do this easily? I'm asking because I have a list of hundreds of Domains with their respective visits and want to place them in Group A or B such that the total visits and number of sites per Domain Group is optimized (meaning, total sites per domain group is as equal as possible)

---

Edit:

My actual list of values (without the actual domain names)

```
Domains:    Views:

Domain 1    118,777
Domain 2    84,108
Domain 3    17,595
Domain 4    17,595
Domain 5    14,201
Domain 6    13,682
Domain 7    8,412
Domain 8    7,685
Domain 9    7,549
Domain 10   6,602
Domain 11   5,631
Domain 12   5,603
Domain 13   5,271
Domain 14   4,533
Domain 15   4,051
Domain 16   4,051
Domain 17   3,682
Domain 18   3,363
Domain 19   1,983
Domain 20   975
Domain 21   792
Domain 22   768
Domain 23   151
Domain 24   17
Domain 25   1
Domain 26   1
Domain 27   1
Domain 28   1
Domain 29   0
Domain 30   0
Domain 31   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to get quite close is to assign a random number to each value (domain), then assign A or B if over/under 0.5. Then sumif for A and B, then keep hitting F9 until you get a good enough answer - or set up a simple macro to keep re calculating till you get close enough.

I use this approach all the time, its quick and simple. In fact i used it today!! Hysterics!

HTH
Ross

Comment: How would this factor in the total views per domain that I want to capture? Can you give an example? I added my actual values above

Comment: The number of views is the thing you sum